# Tomcat7 incomplete by default?

Tags: java, tomcat

I installed tomcat7-standalone and downloaded tomcat7-source and found a wired problem:

The class `org.apache.jasper.JspC`(tomcat7-source) imports `org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader` that i cant find in plain installation of tomcat7-standalone.

IMO this code must throw a CNFE! Right?

```
    if (jspcLoader instanceof AntClassLoader) {
        classPath += File.pathSeparator
            + ((AntClassLoader) jspcLoader).getClasspath();
    }
```

Could that be that tomcat-developers hopes that noone uses their code? Is this ok?

Comment: maybe you didn't [read the documentation about installing ant](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/building.html)?

Comment: @eis I read the documentation and i installed ant, i build it successfully and i run the server without any problems. My question is related to the runtime of the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should, but the [JspC class](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/JspC.html) is not a part of the Tomcat runtime - it is the command-line tool used to [precompile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-0790/abxcc/index.html) the JSPs, and it can be used as an [Ant task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jspc.html) or even as part of [Gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677277/running-tomcat-jasper-task-jspc-with-gradle-build).

Comment: And the code compiles because developers are expected to have `ant` installed: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/building.html

Comment: Ok, but i am correct if i assume that a instanceof requires a class loaded in the virtual-machine?

Comment: That's right, and since Ant is running the `jspc` the class in question is already there.